# How to read a tab formatted text in a textarea with JavaScript (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js

I am trying to read a text that is the product of copying in a word table, so the format is so confuse.

I need to separate the rows as an objects in a array, with the columns as properties of that object, all of this things using Vuejs (ES6) or JavaScript

This is a screenshot of the word table with his columns:
[word screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQEy.png)

```
.code           
        Input   
        store   N
        load    cero
        store   sum 
    initWhile   Load    N
        sub cero
        jz  endWhile
        load    sum
        add N
        store   Sum
        load    n
        sub Uno
        Store   N
        jmp initWhile
    endWhile    load    sum
        output  
        halt    
.data           
    n       
    Cero        
    Sum     
    Uno     

    def uno 01
```

There is the way how the data is copied in the word table, apparently is based on tab, but sometimes the info is overlaying other columns.

Comment: Please post your attempted code or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can advise further or build possible solutions from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple as this:

```
var lines = this.table.split("\n");
```

The bug was in the format that I was pasting in the textbox.
Complete code in my [GitHub](https://github.com/JulianGarzon22/AssemblyVuejs/blob/master/src/components/Conversor.vue)